# S3 appending random string in file name

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a s3 folder with a csv file stored on it. I'm trying to download the last modified file. I'm using this script to get the last modified file:

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=s3_extra_data['aws_access_key_id'],                               
aws_secret_access_key=s3_extra_data['aws_secret_access_key'])
response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket='test', Prefix='file_r/')
all = response['Contents']
latest = max(all, key=lambda x: x['LastModified'])
response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket='test', Prefix=latest["Key"])[:-52].lower())
all = response['Contents']
latest = max(all, key=lambda x: x['LastModified'])
print("LATEST ->" + str(latest["Key"])[:-52].lower())
print("PATH ->" + str(latest["Key"]))
s3_client.download_file("test", latest["Key"], str(latest["Key"]))
```

This code lists my last modified object, the file name is `part-00000-40f267f2-38dc-4bab-811c-4c3052fdb1ba-c000.csv` and is inside the `file_r` folder.

Although, when I use `s3_client.download_file` i get the following error:

```
'file_r/part-00000-40f267f2-38dc-4bab-811c-4c3052fdb1ba-c000.csv.8cEebaeb'
```

When i print my path and my file I get the correct values

```
 LATEST -> file_r/part
 PATH -> file_r/part-00000-40f267f2-38dc-4bab-811c-4c3052fdb1ba-c000.csv
```

Why the value `.8cEebaeb` is appended after the `.csv` extension since the PATH is correct.

Any thoughs on that?

Comment: When you print LATEST, you're not actually printing the whole value; you're printing `str(latest["Key"])[:-52].lower()`, which skips the last 52 characters.  Try printing the whole value so you can accurately see what the string contains.

Comment: Also, where is `path` defined?

Comment: @JohnGordon About your first comment, it prints the correct value (without appending random value in the end). About your second comment, PATH is `latest["Key"]`. I've eddited the question to correct this.

Comment: What error do you get?  What line fails?  boto3 will add a random suffix to a file while downloading, then rename the file when it's done.

Comment: @AnonCoward I solved the problem. I post the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem I changed the code to:

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=s3_extra_data['aws_access_key_id'],                               
aws_secret_access_key=s3_extra_data['aws_secret_access_key'])
response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket='test', Prefix='file_r/')
all = response['Contents']
latest = max(all, key=lambda x: x['LastModified'])
s3_client.download_file("test", latest["Key"], "FILE_NAME"))
```

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue when the local folder is not created.

```
folder1/folder2/filename.foo
```

If folder1 or folder2 does not exist locally, boto3 returns error :

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'folder1/folder2/finemane.foo.F89bdcAc'
```

Comment: +1 for me, when the folder is not created. This feels like a bug, that can't possibly be being done deliberately, it makes the whole error message nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Please note that this issue can sometime happen due to number of char in the folder path in windows machines including the file name.  I faced similar issue and when I tried to save to the same folder path it was giving me error till the time I reduced the number of char to 228.

Comment: This helped me out. I reduced the path character count from 131 to 112 and it worked. I am using Windows.